# Submitting form on radio button click requires additional refresh

Tags: html, onclick, radio-button, form-submit

When you submit the form via clicking the radio button, it inserts properly into database and what appears to refresh the page (and query the database).  However, after clicking the radio button (and inserting information into the database) it shows the old information.  Doing a manual refresh (F5 or refresh button) will then display the new updated information.  How can this be fixed?  Much help appreciated.  Thanks!

```
if(isset($_POST['rate'.$id2.''])) {
            $query94 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO statusRatings(statusID,userID,raterID,rating) VALUES(:statusID,:userID,:raterID,:rating)');
    $query94->execute(array(
        ':statusID' => $id2,
        ':userID' => $profileID,
        ':raterID' => $memberID,
        ':rating' => $_POST['rate'.$id2.'']
    ));
        }

        echo '<form name="rating'.$id2.'" class="form-group" method="POST" action="">
    <ul>
   <li><input id="radio1'.$id2.'" type="radio" onclick="javascript: submit()" name="rate'.$id2.'" value="1"/>
    <label for="radio1'.$id2.'"></label>
    <li><input id="radio2'.$id2.'" type="radio" onclick="javascript: submit()" name="rate'.$id2.'" value="2"/>
    <label for="radio2'.$id2.'"></label>
    <li><input id="radio3'.$id2.'" type="radio" onclick="javascript: submit()" name="rate'.$id2.'" value="3"/>
    <label for="radio3'.$id2.'"></label>
    <li><input id="radio4'.$id2.'" type="radio" onclick="javascript: submit()" name="rate'.$id2.'" value="4"/>
    <label for="radio4'.$id2.'"></label>
    <li><input id="radio5'.$id2.'" type="radio" onclick="javascript: submit()" name="rate'.$id2.'" value="5"/>
    <label for="radio5'.$id2.'"></label>
</ul>
        </form>';
```

Comment: In shorter words, after clicking the radio button, the change doesn't show right away.

Comment: And unrelated, I don't need an explanation for this I'll find it myself... to have text google.com for example inserted as a link a href blah blah, would I use preg_replace for that?